# ASP.Net mvc, show image doesn't affect browser URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have made image gallery. And it works. But I maybe made a mistake that I can pay too much now :( I don't know.

I have a `ImageGalleryController` with `Index` action that returns `IndexView` with list of images.

When I navigate there browser URL is: `localhost/mysite/gallery`

When user click on image I made ajax call (with jquery). To action sethod `ShowImage`. `ShowImageView` contain full browser div with image in it. When I call show image I pass clicked imageID. After getting all needed data I return `ShowImageView`.

In ajax call on success I do:

```
$(document.body).append(resultViewShowImage);
```

And "ShowImageView" is displayed on top of my site. And here I can navigate images etc. It all works grat.

But now the **huge problem**:

When I display `ShowImageView` it is a div positioned on top of my site, and URL stay the same `localhost/mysite/gallery`, when I navigate images inside url is not changing.

I know that I made huge mistake here but what is the proper way to fix this. Can I do something with routing or maybe to display this "ShowImageView" in some other way (not appending it to body)?

I am trying to figure how 'flickr' display this top view but no luck :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at how flickr does it, and compare browsers, you see that they do not change the url in IE8 for example. I would change [the url using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page/3354511#3354511) when the user switches pages, and use these changes to also work as parameters to your controller.

Edit:

Changing the url is only one part of the solution. For example: change the url to localhost/mysite/gallery/1 when the first image is shown, using JavaScript. This url would then point to the gallery controller with the number 1 as a parameter.

After that, in your controller, you have to see what the parameter is and based on that choose what image to display.

Comment: But is this only solution. Is it possible that for example g+ and facebook works the same way? If I give that url to another user then he can't directly navigate to this image with custom combined url...